# Internet speed limited to 100Mbps on gigabit ethernet connection

Tags: ubuntu, ethernet, internet

Acording to Speedtest.net my speed is 100Mbps. This is the case if I plug the ethernet cable in the designated rj45 slot.

If instead i use a usb Lan adapter the speed is normal ~950Mbps

I use Ubuntu 20.04

Heres some info:

```
$ ethtool eno1
Settings for eno1:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                         1000baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
```

```
$ lshw -c network
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 38:f3:ab:a3:f9:bb
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.048.00-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.100.19 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:49 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d1804000-d1804fff memory:d1800000-d1803fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 74:4c:a1:be:7f:49
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw89_pci driverversion=5.11.0-43-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:94 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d1700000-d17fffff
*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@2:2.3.3
       logical name: eth0
       serial: 00:0e:c6:82:01:1b
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ax88179_178a driverversion=5.11.0-43-generic duplex=half link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
```

Comment: bets are on your router. Typically highly price-optimized things, doing random things internally.

Comment: Same port on the router in both cases? Green or orange indicator light on the port? Same cable in both cases? Does it have a "CAT" label on the cable (not an animal, but CAT as in CATegory)?

Comment: @MarcusMüller If i boot into windows with same configuration i get the expected speed.

Comment: @roaima Same port, same cable, green light, i can confirm the cable is good.

Comment: `dmesg | grep rtl_nic` ... can you see any firmware being loaded for the ethernet port? If not, perhaps some error/warning in `dmesg` about firmware? you could `apt install firmware-realtek`

Comment: I think Speedtest measures the speed of your machine's connection to the internet, not the speed of its connection to the local network. So you might have 1Gbit/s speed over LAN and 0.1Gbit/s speed over internet.